# error clob (oracle) value in code igniter, how to solve it?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oracle11g, codeigniter-2

i have data in my oracle and retrieve it from codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('detail');
$r = $this->db->get($tableName);
$result = $r->result();
```

print_r($result) :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DETAIL] => OCI-Lob Object
                (
                    [descriptor] => Resource id #80
                )
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DETAIL] =>
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DETAIL] => OCI-Lob Object
                (
                    [descriptor] => Resource id #80
                )
        )
)
```

data model :

```
function get_ora_blob_value($value)
{
    $size = $value->size();
    $result = $value->read($size);
    return ($result)?$result:NULL;
}
```

retrieving data :

```
echo $this->data->get_ora_blob_value($result[0][DETAIL]); // should be 'remark1'
echo "<br />";
echo $this->data->get_ora_blob_value($result[1][DETAIL]); // should be null
echo "<br />";
echo $this->data->get_ora_blob_value($result[2][DETAIL]); // should be 'remark2'
```

printed :

```
remark2 
(empty) 
(empty)
```

why first data has value of third data? and third data become empty?

Comment: What would be the result of `print_r($r->result_array())` ? What would be printed if you using `foreach($result as $single_result)` to retrieve your data?

Answer (score 1):

There is only two things to remember in codeigniter.

If you know that you have only one row of data to be returned then you have to use `row_array().` In your case `$result = $r->row_array();` and to retrieve its value you will use `$result['column_name'];`.

In case of multiple rows we use result(), in your case `$result = $r->result();` and you have to loop through those multiple rows in this way `foreach $result as $val { $val->column_name;  }`, `$val->column_name;` will give you the value.

Comment: yups .. sorry for my mistaken code ..
but i found all oracle data in clob type will not has it's real value if data has more than one records.
As you see the decriptor always point to id 80